# Repeated string pattern: difference between the FrontEnd and WolframScript?

Tags: front-end, pattern-matching, string-manipulation, parsing, input-forms

This code works fine in a string based interface like WolframScript or Mathematica Kernel.

Run this through a string based interface

```
StringCases["hello", x_..]
```

Or do

```
ToExpression["StringCases[\"hello\", x_..]"]
```

in the notebook. Both work correctly, `x_..` is interpreted as a [`Repeated`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Repeated.html) form of the pattern `x_`,

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z@4pCgzL905sTi1OFopIzUnJ19JR6EiXk8v9v///7oFQMkSAA)

In the notebook based front end, however, it fails because `x_.` is interpreted as a [`Default`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Default.html) pattern and the second dot throws a syntax error.

[image]

The code must be modified to

```
StringCases["hello", (x_)..]
(*    {"h", "e", "ll", "o"}    *)
```

Why is there a difference in behavior between the front end and kernel parsers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect, much to my chagrin, that the FE is right and the InputForm parser is wrong.  For one thing, the kernel itself thinks that parens are needed for `Repeated`:

```
Repeated[Pattern[x,Blank[]]]//InputForm
(*(x_)..*)
```

The reason it breaks in the FE is that the FE treats the x_. as a single token: `RowBox[{"x_.", "."}]`.  And that's absolutely correct: see tutorial/OperatorInputForms and the section "Spaces to Avoid", because "x_." is a "special input form".  On the other hand, .. is a normal operator, so it is another token.  For example a.. is `RowBox[{"a", ".."}]`.  So the question is whether "x_.." should be `RowBox[{"x_.","."}]` or `RowBox[{"x_",".."}]`.  And what happens if something is added after the second dot? Now, according the precednece tables, forms involving `_` have higher precedence than pretty much any operator (MessageName seems to be the lone exception).  In which case the FE is doing the right thing.  I'll ruminate and discuss some more whether that's the resolution, but this is clearly a bug one way or the other.

P.S. We do take these differences seriously, especially when easily typable input parses differently in the two contexts.

Comment: "P.S. We do take these differences seriously, especially when easily typable input parses differently in the two contexts."
I have many, many examples. See my links above if you are interested.

Comment: Today I collected a few of them here: https://wltools.github.io/LanguageSpec/Resources/KernelVsFE. I have not included difference in operator precedence on that page.

Comment: I see several errors on that page.  Most signifcantly, FullForm doesn't depend on the environment--parsing of an input might be context-dependent, but once you have an expression its FullForm is unambiguous.  However, you also point out real issues (many of which are known).  For example the Times issue you point out is not, in fact, always, semantically insignificant (for finite precision arithmetic).  We actually have a fix for that in our internal prototype build and I'm optimistic it will make into our next major release.  I am happy to discuss further in some suitable venue.

Comment: @RobertJackson I will note that Itai spent significant time testing and debugging the pending changes to the kernel times/unary minus parsing.

Comment: "Most signifcantly, FullForm doesn't depend on the environment..."
I assume you are referring to differences between systems. I haven't witnessed it—I am just quoting the docs which might be incorrect. Thanks for the correction re: the `Times` issue. I will need to correct the page. Let me know of any other errors. You're the first person from Wolfram to express any interest in this, as most of it has been known to be broken for years. If you would like more, I can look through my notes. (That website was motivated by differences in operator precedence between notebook and command line.)

Comment: @ItaiSeggev Since you are the unary minus expert, can I suggest that the Unicode minus symbol should be able to be used in any place the ASCII symbol can?

Comment: @RobertJacobson No, I was referring to your claim that "any expression for which the FE and command line give different FullForm expressions also have different hashes in each."  Once you have an expression, it's FullForm is unambgious and so its is hash.  I agree there are inputs that produce different expressions between the FE.  But the FullForm is not a property of the input (which may be given in any of several ways), it is a property of the expression.  BTW for "Expression" the issues are primarily things like word size or byte order that might affect the arithmetic--less relevant today.

Comment: About Unicode minus.  So there are the raw number forms where you have to use ASCII minus.  Are there others?  I have to say that my gut reaction this would be a lot of effort for not very much gain.  Indeed possibly a loss--you'll have gone from a situation where `\[Minus]` is always subtraction (whether unary or binary) to one where it might inadvertently be soaked up by a number to its left.  If you know of other situations or can describe why you care, that might affect our assessment.

Comment: @ItaiSeggev Could we move to a better venue for technical conversation? I'd also like to ask you more about the times issue. Let me suggest either or both of Wolfram Language Slack workspace: https://wolfr.am/LmVzbTQt   GitHub issues: https://wolfr.am/LmVCyFV5

Answer (score 11):

The notebook interface and the kernel have different parsers, because the notebook needs to manipulate the input before the kernel sees it for a variety of reasons. There are many differences between the two parsers. It has not been a priority to Wolfram to fix the differences.

I have been trying to [catalog the differences here](https://github.com/WLTools/LanguageSpec) ([rendered as a webpage here](https://wltools.github.io/LanguageSpec/)). Most differences are semantically equivalent, but some are meaningful, as  you have discovered.

Comment: I have, with some considerable effort, attempted to spelunk your interesting website for the list of FE/kernel differences, and I've not been able to find any at all.  Could you point specifically to where I can find your enumerated list of differences?

Comment: The website is a bit broken. Sorry for that. I'll see if I can fix it today. The easiest place to find differences is in the table of operator precedences. There are also some differences mentioned elsewhere. The site isn't organized for the purpose of pointing out these differences, though. Given that both you and @Itai Seggev have shown interest in the subject, maybe I should write up something and post it in question form here on SE.

Comment: @JohnFultz I collected a few of them here: https://wltools.github.io/LanguageSpec/Resources/KernelVsFE/. I have not included difference in operator precedence on that page.

Comment: @JohnFultz "I have, with some considerable effort, attempted to spelunk" Perhaps. But that's still not the right way to spell lunk.